# Determine time complexity when loop has multiplication factor

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I am newbie in  time complexity.Probably the question may be very easy.

```
public void test(int n)
{
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i=i*5)
  {
      System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

Above code has one loop and the frequency of the loop is determined by (i=i*5).
Can someone help to find time complexity of below code.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm has time complexity O(log n).
Since the multiplication is by 5, specifically we can say that the time complexity is of the order of log n to the base 5.